# Android emulator does not open in visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, mobile, maui

[enproblem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlp8X.png)

I wanted to run the program I just created, but it gave an error message and the android emulator was not installed.

According to my research, it should be android sdk, unfortunately I can't find anything.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you install the android sdk with the Tools->android->SDK manager?